# Understanding a proof about the only normal subgroups of $S_5$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, symmetric-groups

I am trying to understand the proof that the only normal subgroups of $S_5$ are $\{1\}$, $A_5$, and $S_5$. The proof starts as follows:

> Suppose $H \trianglelefteq S_5$. Restrict $\operatorname{sgn}:S_5 \mapsto\{\pm 1\}$ to $H$. If $H \leq A_5$ then $H \trianglelefteq A_5$ (**why??**), so $H = \{1\}$ or $A_5$ because $A_5$ is simple. Thus, assume that $H$ contains both even and odd permutations, so that $H \cap A_5 \trianglelefteq A_5$. Thus, $H\cap A_5 = \{1\}$ or $A_5$. In the second case $H=S_5$. In the first case, $H \cong \{\pm 1\}$ (**Why? I don't understand the following part**) because $\operatorname{sgn}:H \mapsto\{\pm 1\}$ is onto and $A_5 \cap H = \operatorname{Ker}(\operatorname{sgn})\cap H = \{1\}$. Thus, ... (**I understand the rest of the proof**)

I would appreciate help understand the parts in bold. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, if $H \trianglelefteq S_5$ and we have $H \leq A_5 \leq S_5$, then $H \trianglelefteq A_5$. This is because if $sHs^{-1} \in H$ for each $s \in S_5$, then because $A_5$ is a subset of $S_5$, $aHa^{-1} \in H$ for each $a \in A_5$.

In the second part, I'm not sure what it means for $H$ to be isomorphic to $\{\pm 1\}$ since $\{\pm 1\}$ are just the signs of the permutations and not group elements. Maybe the author is looking at the map $\operatorname{sgn} \colon H \to \{\pm1\}$ and saying that $H \cong \operatorname{Im}\operatorname{sgn}/\operatorname{Ker}\operatorname{sgn}$, and $\operatorname{Ker}\operatorname{sgn}$ has only a single element?

Comment: I think the second part is simply the first isomorphism theorem applied to the homomorphism $\text{sgn} : H \to \{1, -1\}$. This homomorphism is surjective since $H$ contains both even and odd elements. Therefore $H / \text{ker}(\text{sgn})$ is isomorphic to the image of $\text{sgn}$, which is $\{1, -1\}$. Moreover, the kernel consists exactly of the even permutations in $H$. But $H \cap A_5 = \{1\}$, so the only even permutation in $H$ is the identity. So the kernel is trivial, hence $H$ is isomorphic to $\{1, -1\}$.

Comment: P.S. Here we are viewing $\{1, -1\}$ as a group under integer multiplication.

Comment: @Bungo I also think this is what it means, I guess it is simply implied that $H / \{1\}$ is isomorphic to $H$?

Comment: @b_pcakes Yes, $H$ consists of elements of the form $x$, whereas $H/\{1\}$ simply wraps each element into a singleton set of the form $\{x\}$. In terms of group theory this distinction is irrelevant. To see the isomorphism formally, consider the identity map $i : H \to H$. This is certainly an isomorphism, with kernel $\{1\}$ and image $H$. Now apply the first isomorphism theorem to conclude that $H/\{1\} \cong H$.